# Node JS await call returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await, undefined

The problem is that when I make a POST call to `/login`, the `const user` gets assigned undefined even though `getUser()` always returns the same value. The call `console.log(getUser());` at the end of the file works fine.

I simplified and unified the code.

index.js

```
const express = require("express");
const secret = "123456789";
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const mariadb = require('mariadb');
const pool = mariadb.createPool({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: "test",
    connectionLimit: 5
});

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

async function getUser()  {
    let conn;
    try {
        conn = await pool.getConnection();
        const rows = await conn.query("SELECT 'John' as username");
        console.log(rows); // Prints [ { username: 'John' } ]
        return rows;
    } catch (err) {
        throw err;
    } finally {
        if (conn) return conn.end();
    }
}

app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    const user = await getUser();

    console.log(user); // Prints undefined
    if (!user) {
        return res.status(401).send({
            success: false,
            msg: "Usuario o contraseña incorrecta"
        })
    }

    if (user) {
        const payload = {
            id: user.email,
            dni: user.dni
        };

        const token = jwt.sign(payload, secret, { expiresIn: "1d" });
        return res.status(200).send({
            success: true,
            token: 'Bearer ' + token
        })
    }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});

console.log(getUser());
```

package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.0",
    "mariadb": "^3.1.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.22",
    "passport": "^0.6.0"
  }
}
```

I played around with the async/await, looked through the documentation and searched similar problems but can't find what is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you have a `return` statement in the `finally` block.

When you have a return in your `finally` block, the `return`s in `try` or `catch` blocks do not get executed. So, your function returns the result of `return conn.end();`.

Remove the `return` word from the `finally` block and the function should return what you expect.

Comment: It works. But why when I made the call `console.log(getUser());` at the end of the code doesn't returns `undefined` ?

Comment: `getUser()` is an async function and it returns a `Promise` that resolves to something. When you called `console.log(getUser());` you are not awaiting for the resolution of the promise, so you get a `Promise` object. To get the resolution, you need to do like this: `console.log(await getUser());`

Comment: When I call `console.log(getUser());` at the end of the file it returns `[ { username: 'John' } ]`, even tho im not using `await`. Thats what I don't get, it returns different values depending where I call it from.

Answer (score 0):

[MDN finally-block documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch#the_finally-block):

> Control flow statements (`return`, `throw`, `break`, `continue`) in the `finally` block will "mask" any completion value of the `try` block or `catch` block. In this example, the try block tries to return 1, but before returning, the control flow is yielded to the `finally` block first, so the `finally` block's return value is returned instead.
>
> ```
> function doIt() {
>   try {
>     return 1;
>   } finally {
>     return 2;
>   }
> }
>
> doIt(); // returns 2
> ```
>
> It is generally a bad idea to have control flow statements in the `finally` block. Only use it for cleanup code.